# Jquery modal prompt before excel import (using MVC 3)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog, prompt

Currently I have a link on mvc webgrid page when you click takes you to a view that renders excel results. But, I want to give users another option to include more details. So, I want to add a modal prompt with 2 radio buttons "Export Results" (what is displayed now) and "Export Results with Member details" before going to the view passing "ReportId" (1 or 2). 
Here's my code, My view would change from MemberstoExcel() to MemberstoExcel(ReportId) with the user input?

The link in search view:

```
 {@Html.ActionLink("Export Results", "MembersToExcel")}
```

The code in the controller:

```
public ActionResult MemberstoExcel()
    {
        var db= new Models.MemberDB();
        Spreadsheet mySpreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();

        MemberSearch member = new MemberSearch();

        var contents =  TempData["searchResults"];
        IDictionary<string, string> searchConditions = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        if (TempData["SearchConditions"] != null)
        {
            searchConditions = TempData["SearchConditions"] as Dictionary<string, string>;
        }

        this.TempData["SearchConditions"] = searchConditions;

         ..... code removed for readability......

        var results = db.GetMembers(member);
        mySpreadsheet.contents = results;
        mySpreadsheet.fileName = "MemberResults.xls";
        return View(mySpreadsheet);
    }
```

The code in excel view:

```
 <ss:Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
    <ss:Table>
    @foreach (var content in Model.contents)
    {
        <ss:Row>

            <ss:Cell>
                <ss:Data ss:Type="String">@content.fullname</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
                <ss:Data ss:Type="String">@content.email</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
                <ss:Data ss:Type="String">@content.companyname</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
                <ss:Data ss:Type="String">@content.regDate</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
                <ss:Data ss:Type="String">@content.country</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
                <ss:Data ss:Type="String">@content.modifiedDate</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
                <ss:Data ss:Type="String">@content.ciscontactid</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
        </ss:Row>
    }
    </ss:Table>
</ss:Worksheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you say "modal prompt" in the context of a web application, my mind always goes to javascript, specifically jQuery.  There are tons of open-source modal prompt jQuery plugins.  It would be trivial to pass a conditional querystring value depending on the user's selection in the popup, thereby allowing them to change the output.

Here's a tutorial on a modal popup with jQuery:
http://www.queness.com/post/77/simple-jquery-modal-window-tutorial

Comment: thanks I was thinking Jquery for the solution. Yes, I saw that example prior.